# Value of a signed short in memory (endianness)

Tags: c, memory, int, unsigned, signed

So I got this :

```
  adress |   a   |  a+1  |  a+2  |  a+3
  bytes  |  0x80 | 0x00  | 0x00  | 0x01
```

I need to know which number is represented in :

- Little endian, unsigned int (16777344 to me)
- Big endian, unsigned int (2147483649 to me)
- Little endian, int (still 16777344 to me)
- Big endian, int (-2147483647 because of Two's complement, which is !number + 1)
- -Big endian, short ( -(2**15 +1) to me)
- -Little endian, short (128 to me)
- -Big endian, unsigned short ( 32768 to me)
- -Little    endian, unsigned short (128 to me)

Did I make any mistake ?

Comment: Your answers look about right.  You could do worse than writing a little test program to confirm.

Comment: Just at the explanation of the 2's complement you should write `~number + 1` instead of the logical negation, which evaluates to one or zero only.